# How to put a variable in quotes?

Tags: php, concatenation

I have a variable `$teste = hiiiii`

I need to put the variable inside a quote and a double quote.
Like this:

`"'$teste'"` for the value be this `"'hiiiii'"`

I'm trying concatenation but not working. How do that???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can escape your quotes:](http://ideone.com/vUUhDS)

```
echo "\"'$teste'\"";
```

will print out: `"'hiiiii'"`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$result = '"\'' . $teste . '\'"';
```

this will result in: `"'hiiiii'"`.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepad.org/bzvBVbeL)

Comment: `\'` will not be unescaped since it occurs withing a single quoted string

Comment: I stand corrected.... I was basing that on `'\n'` not being unescaped while in single quotes.

Comment: @Orangepill: In fact, it's one of the two things that *will* be unescaped.  (The other is \\ .)  (Damn Markdown.)

Answer (score 0):

Using basic cheat of  single and double quote

```
$test = 'hi';
echo '"'."'".$test."'".'"';
echo "'".'"'.$test.'"'."'";
```